# Simple visit duration logger with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, events, get

I have problem with logging visit duration.

I wrote test html file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

            function enter() {
                this.chrono = new Date().getMilliseconds();
                alert("test");
            }

            function leave() {
                this.chrono = new Date().getMilliseconds() - this.chrono;

                var myAjax = new Ajax.Request('visitor_log/ajax_store_visit_duration.php?visit_duration=' + this.chrono.toString(),{
                        method: 'get',
                        onComplete:handlerFunction
                });

                return null;
            }

            window.onload = enter;
            window.onbeforeunload = leave;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP file (visitor_log/ajax_store_visit_duration.php):

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET["visit_duration"]))
{
    $text = $_GET["visit_duration"];

    log($text);
}
else die("error");

function log($text)
{
    $myFile = "test.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'wb');
    fwrite($fh, $text);
    fclose($fh);
}

?>
```

When I type in browser:

`http://localhost/visitor_log/ajax_store_visit_duration.php?visit_duration=123`

it creates text file as I want, but it seems that AJAX call in `onbeforeunload` event is not working.

**Whats wrong with my code?**

---

Edit:

I created test function to find problem with AJAX call.

```
        function testajax(){
            this.chrono = new Date().getMilliseconds() - this.chrono;

           var blockingRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            blockingRequest.open("GET", "visitor_log/ajax_store_visit_duration.php?visit_duration=" + 123, false); // async = false
            blockingRequest.send();

            return null;
        }

        window.onload = testajax;
    </script>
</body>
```

This is not working too.

Comment: What/where is `handlerFunction`?

Comment: There is no such function... I took that code from some page... Can I just remove that handlerFunction?

Comment: You'll have to make the AJAX call synchronous, otherwise there's a good chance the browser will abort/stop the request as it unloads

Comment: Also, note that `language="JavaScript"` is deprecated and not needed anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so purposefully NOT using jQuery:

here's the PHP:

```
<?php

function loggit($text) {
    $myFile = "/tmp/test.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'wb');
    fwrite($fh, $text);
    fclose($fh);
}

if(isset($_GET["visit_duration"])) {
    $text = $_GET["visit_duration"];
    loggit($text);
}
else die("error");

?>
```

here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    function enter() {
        this.chrono = new Date().getMilliseconds();
    }

    function leave() {
        this.chrono = new Date().getMilliseconds() - this.chrono;

        alert("test" + this.chrono);

    var blockingRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    blockingRequest.open("GET", "http://localhost/_TempFiles/temp.php?visit_duration=" + this.chrono.toString(), false); // async = false
    blockingRequest.send();

        return null;
    }

    window.onload = enter;
    window.onbeforeunload = leave;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

you want to use an async request (see the false sent to blockingrequest.open) - but beware this is a BLOCKING request (hence the name).

Also I changed the name of the php function from "log" to "loggit" log is the php natural logarithm function...

Comment: This is not working too. I created test function for this, see question update.

Comment: Strange, it works for me. I'm editing the original reply with the full source for both files as they are short. Note, you will need to replace the http://localhost/_TempFiles/temp.php URL with your URL in the html file.

Comment: I changed `log` function to `logtxt` and... it worked. Thats weird, because it was working when I tried to use that function earlier...

Comment: Oh, cool. Well then the full HTML and PHP I just put up is unnecessary... but now you see it. For future people, the gist is we changed the JS to the three lines with the "blockingRequest"...

Comment: It works for you? What browser are you using? Im not getting alert or anything when this request is in `onbeforeunload` event handler.

Comment: It works in Chrome. Doesnt work in Opera, but I think this is new problem for new question. Thanks.